# H2o not fully accessing memory on a cluster

Tags: r, cluster-computing, h2o

So this may be odd, but H2O doesn't seem to be accessing the memory available to it in my cluster.  It is supposed to be using 24 cores and 512GB total RAM but only sees 26.67 Gb of RAM (but all 24 cores).  I am running H2o in R.

```
h2o.init(nthreads=-1,max_mem_size = "500g")

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
/tmp/Rtmpx9ndSU/h2o_ra2816_started_from_r.out
/tmp/Rtmpx9ndSU/h2o_ra2816_started_from_r.err

openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: . Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
H2O cluster uptime:         1 seconds 304 milliseconds 
H2O cluster version:        3.10.5.2 
H2O cluster version age:    4 days  
H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_ra2816_qpf255 
H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
H2O cluster total memory:   26.67 GB 
H2O cluster total cores:    24 
H2O cluster allowed cores:  24 
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
H2O Connection port:        54321 
H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
R Version:                  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
```

I would appreciate any help or ideas about the issue.

Comment: Can you run a 'ps' command to see what -Xmx option is passed to the java process?  And include the log output from the .out and .err files shown.

Comment: I cant check the source code now but from what I remember we map that max mem to Java's XMx argument, it does not allocate all the memory upfront and might report a much lower value at the beginning. 2 thinga you can try 1) try setting this to a much lower value (5-20G) and see it works 2) try uploading over 26.67G of data - my guess it is the jvm will expand and work properly. Might get slow due to swapping if you go over your physicall ram, though.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The ps command results in this: PID TTY          TIME CMD
14396 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
14968 pts/0    00:00:04 java
16046 pts/0    00:00:37 java
16204 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I can load an object larger than 26.67gb (a 37gb .csv file for example) but H2O will randomly run out of java heap space somewhere in the middle of any program.

Comment: @TomKraljevic I don't know how to access the log outputs.  I have a node provisioned to me and I don't see the /tmp/ anywhere in my directories once I quit R.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk There isn't any swapping going on when I looked.  I looked at the node: NodeName=node047 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=12
   CPUAlloc=24 CPUErr=0 CPUTot=24 CPULoad=2.29
   AvailableFeatures=mem512
   ActiveFeatures=mem512
   Gres=(null)
   NodeAddr=node047 NodeHostName=node047 Version=16.05
   OS=Linux RealMemory=512000 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=449373 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=ALLOCATED ThreadsPerCore=1 TmpDisk=0 Weight=2 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A

Comment: @RaagAgrawal Just to check -- you are running these commands from your cluster machine with 512GB directly (and not a laptop or a master node that has less memory)?

Comment: You need to give 'ps' options to print out the arguments to the program.  'ps -efww' for example.  For the logs, look at the /tmp directory before you exit R.

Comment: I just tried this on my machine, same H2O version `3.10.5.2`, a bit never Java (but 8), R 3.4 and I got `H2O cluster total memory:   444.44 GB`. Maybe this is something related to your environment? Where are you running it? AWS? Something else? Is it possible your admin is restricting the max memory per process on it?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I am running it on a University cluster.  I'm allotted a node with 24 cores and 512gb physical memory.  I can't actually access the node outside my terminal window, even from another terminal (so I can't seem to run 'ps' on it).  I will inquire with the admins to see if it's an issue on their end.  Good to know it's not an issue with H2O.

Comment: It could be an OpenJDK vs. Oracle Java thing.

Comment: @TomKraljevic thank you for your help.  I have solved the issue. The node was provisioned to only offer 26.67 memory to java.  I just ran: options(java.parameters = "-Xmx500000m") before initializing H2O and now it recognizes all the available memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue.  By putting the following before initializing H2O:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx500000m")
```